# Zend Regex Router does not match anything

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, routes

I currently have a Zend Framework route defined as such:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('brand/:brand_name/series/:page',
                                                array('controller' => 'brand',
                                                    'action' => 'series',
                                                    'page'=>'1'));
$router->addRoute('Brand Series', $route);
```

I'm trying to adapt this route so that the page parameter only catches numbers, so that I can add another route that uses words in the same place without the two conflicting, something like:

```
brand/:brand_name/series/:series_name/:page
```

I figured I would step along with the examples in the ZF documentation [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex). The very first step would be to change the route to something like this:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('brand/:brand_name/series/(\d+)',
                                                array('controller' => 'brand',
                                                    'action' => 'series'));
```

However, this small change causes routes that matched perfectly before, like `/brand/johnnycupcakes/series/2` to fail, telling me `Action "johnnycupcakes" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()`. And in the stack trace I see:

```
'controller' => 'brand',
'action' => 'johnnycupcakes',
'series' => '2',
'module' => 'default'
```

In fact, even if I leave the route and default parameters exactly the same as in the first example, and simply change the class to Router_Route_Regex, I get the same error.

I know that the error isn't a routing conflict, because I haven't added the route that would have conflicted. Plus, it appears that it's attempting to match to the standard route. I'm testing this on version 1.11, so my version should be perfectly compatible with the code in the example.

As far as I can tell, the regex route is simply not matching, despite that it very clearly fits. Why could this possibly be failing?

EDIT:
I omitted the addRoute from the question the first time. I always had it in the code, that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to name a captured numeric parameter by adding third argument to `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex`:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'brand/:brand_name/series/(\d+)',
    array(
        'controller' => 'brand',
        'action' => 'series'
    ),
    array(
        1 => 'series', // name the parameter captured by (\d+)
    )
);
```

The second array may have keys and values in opposite relation `'series' => 1` and it will still work. Check more in ZF manual on [regex routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex)

Comment: I've tried that, and it makes no difference. The point of naming the parameters is to make them easier to work with, but it makes no difference if the route doesn't get matched at all. The mapping from the stack trace shows that the route isn't even being matched and it is trying to apply the standard routing to my url.

Comment: @jaimerump did you actually connected the route to router?

Comment: Yeah, the next line is an addRoute. I'll edit the question to show that I included it.